В VS Code не отображается код Unity и выдает ошибку "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis"
Сейчас, когда я создаю новый проект в Unity, код в VS Code у меня обычно не подсвечивается. Также обычно, я решаю эту проблему, обновляя пакет Visual Studio Editor. Но иногда, это не помогает. Я долго бьюсь, царапаюсь, кусаюсь, но решение одно - пересоздавать проект. Сейчас, когда у меня подобная ситуация, я все же решил до конца разобраться в вопросе.
Хотя, этот случай не похож на предыдущие. При заходе в вс код у меня в правом нижнем углу выдает: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: couldn't create connection to server.
Я знаю, что это связано с dotnet, и с расширением C#. У меня есть выходные данные, вот они:

Рядом кстати есть та самая ошибка.
Могу предоставить еще данные, если понадобятся. И главное - пожалуйста, положите конец моим мучениям.

О каком именно расширени речь? Как оно точно называется? Какие .NET расширения установлены? Установлена ли .NET SDK 8.0?
